# JPA orm.xml support for database index

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa, orm

I do not see any option to do something like, in **orm.xml** file, of **JPA2**.

```
<basic name="developer">
    <index />
    <column name="developer"/>
</basic>
```

I see there is **hbm.xml** files, which offers that, but I wonder if **JPA 2.0** really lacks this feature as part of the standard.

so I can avoid the transformation to **hbm.xml** files...

Answer (score 1):

JPA 2.0 `table` XSD type looks like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="table">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="unique-constraint" type="orm:unique-constraint" 
                   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="catalog" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="schema" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

While JPA 2.1 looks as follows:

```
<xsd:complexType name="table">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="unique-constraint" type="orm:unique-constraint" 
                   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xsd:element name="index" type="orm:index" 
                   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="catalog" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="schema" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

So, you don't have the `index` attribute on the `table` type that's provided on a per-entity level:

```
<entity class="Post" access="FIELD">
    <table>
        <index column-list="first_name,last_name" name="name_idx" unique="true"/>
    </table>
    <attributes>
        ...
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

However, you don't need to use `hbm2ddl` in your application. Just [use Flyway instead and you are way better off](https://vladmihalcea.com/flyway-database-schema-migrations/).